# Input 0 of layer "sequential_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), found shape=(None, 324, 500, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, fastapi

I'm  having an issue if anyone can help please comment

```
input_shape=(BATCH_SIZE,256,256,3)
model=models.Sequential([
        resize_and_rescale,
        data_augmentation,

        layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation="relu", input_shape=input_shape),
        layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),

        layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu"),
        layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
        layers.Conv2D(64,kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu"),
        layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
        
        layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation="relu"),
        layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
        layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation="relu"),
        layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
        layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation="relu"),
        layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),

        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(64,activation="relu"),

        layers.Dense(n_classes, activation="softmax")

  ])
  model.build(input_shape=input_shape)
```

this is my model which is working perfectly but when i post image of any size different from 256,256 from postman

```
@app.post("/predict")
async def predict(
file: UploadFile = File(...)
):
image = read_file_as_image(await file.read())
img_batch = np.expand_dims(image, 0)

predictions = MODEL.predict(img_batch)

predicted_class = CLASS_NAMES[np.argmax(predictions[0])]
confidence = np.max(predictions[0])
return {
    'class': predicted_class,
    'confidence': float(confidence)
}

if __name__ == "__main__":
uvicorn.run(app, host='localhost', port=8000)
```

this is what my fast api returns->

Input 0 of layer "sequential_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), found shape=(None, 324, 500, 3)

i tried resizing image from Pillow but it didn't  work , i dont know much about fastapi so if anyone knows how to resolve this error
please comment.

Comment: How did you try to resize the image that didn't work? This is an issue with your input image not matching the expected side for your model, it's not related to FastAPI.

Comment: i tried it using pillow but didn't work now i tried with opencv and it's working thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small correction, the below code is incorrect
img=cv2.resize(img, (256,256,3)

Instead, You have to only mention the pixel size
img = cv2.resize(img, dsize = (256, 256))

Comment: Yes i did same earlier it was obvious to remove that 3 but thanks to upload the correction for other searching the answer

Answer (score 2):

You need resize your image before use this:

```
import cv2
...
image = read_file_as_image(await file.read())
image = cv2.resize(image, (256,256,3))
img_batch = np.expand_dims(image, 0) 
# OR
img_batch = image[None,...]
...
```

More Explanation:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2],[2,3]])

>>> a.shape
(2, 2)

>>> a[None, ...].shape
(1, 2, 2)

>>> np.expand_dims(a, 0).shape
(1, 2, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

what is read_file_as_image(await file.read()), is it a function you wrote?
try this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
img_path= define the full path to the image here
img=plt.imread(img_path)
img=cv2.resize(img, (256,256,3)
img=np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
print (img.shape)
```

Comment: yes i created this function   def read_file_as_image(data) -> np.ndarray:
    image = np.array(Image.open(BytesIO(data)))
    return image